# How to add auto completion for docker compose V2 in bash

Tags: bash, docker, docker-compose

According to [this blog](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/enable-docker-command-completion/) I've tried

```bash
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/docker/docker-ce/master/components/cli/contrib/completion/bash/docker -o /etc/bash_completion.d/docker.sh
```

But `docker compose -f <tab>` will become

```bash
docker compose -f y
yml   yaml
```

instead of giving suggestions from file system.

Documentation only gives guide for the old `docker-compose`: https://docker-docs.netlify.app/compose/completion/

Comment: Are you using bash? Did you relogin?

Comment: Yes I've relogined. `docker.sh` does take effect since `docker comp<tab>` can correctly be completed to `docker compose`. But as I described above, `docker compose -f` does not work.

Comment: `/etc/bash-completion.d` is not honored automatically by bash itself. You need to have the bash-completion package installed and be on an operating system where bash-completion's packaging doesn't modify the places it looks for files to source on startup.

Comment: Beyond that, interactive shell configuration is better suited to [unix.se]; Stack Overflow is narrowly focused on questions about software development and tools exclusive to that purpose.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the canonical source for the completion scripts is located here:

https://github.com/docker/cli/tree/master/contrib/completion

There's a `bash/docker` script in that tree.  So if you load that in shell startup *(or set it up in ~/.bash_completion.d/)* it's reasonable to expect success.

Answer (score -2):

**1-Make sure bash completion is installed. If you use a current Linux in a non-minimal installation, bash completion should be available**

**2-Place the completion script in /etc/bash_completion.d/ with running this script:**

curl -L https://raw.githubusercontent.com/docker/compose/$(docker-compose version --short)/contrib/completion/bash/docker-compose > /etc/bash_completion.d/docker-compose

**3-Relogin**

Comment: How is this materially different from what the OP shows that they're already doing? ("Materially different" meaning, if creating a `/etc/bash-completion.d` file didn't work when they had `curl` do it with the `-o` argument specifying the output file name, why is it supposed to work now when it's done with a redirection?)